# Drag and Drop keyword doesn't seem to work in ExtendedSelenium2Library?

Tags: drag-and-drop, robotframework, selenium2library

I have recently switched jobs and I have started using `RobotFramework` for automating UI-tests. I am a bit stuck with using Drag and Drop keyword from the `ExtendedSelenium2Library`. My custom keyword is as follows:

**Add Goals**

```
drag and drop ${Source} ${Destination}
```

I am calling the above keyword in my test and the test passes 
(meaning it has dragged and dropped), whereas in reality - it hasn't done so. Alternatively, I tried using the below and it didn't seem to work as well.

**Add Goals by mouse**

```
 mouse down    ${Source} 

 mouse up      ${Destination}
```

> The application I am testing is built on Angular JS. The browser I am running is Chrome v-51.0.2704.84

If there is a better way to tackle this or to get it working, it would be of great help!

Thanks,
Vaishnavi.

Comment: It is not the first time this problem has been reported. It might depend on the HTML code or types of elements being dragged-n-dropped. Could this be reproduced with pure Selenium?
Here is an example where first test is OK (using jQuery) and the other is false positive:    Div Based DnD Example
        Open Browser    http://www.elated.com/res/File/articles/development/javascript/jquery/drag-and-drop-with-jquery-your-essential-guide/droppable.html    ${BROWSER}
        Sleep    .2
        Drag And Drop    id=makeMeDraggable    id=makeMeDroppable
        Close All Browsers

Comment: Failed to post example here. The complete example test file is at [http://robotframework.transformidea.com/playground/dragndrop.robot](http://robotframework.transformidea.com/).

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Helio, I have found a workaround by using Mouse up, Mouse move and Mouse down options. Was missing Mouse move above.

Comment: @VaishinaviRajaraman.. i couldnt find Mouse move keyword.... would you eloborate a little on how didu solve this.... i'm stuck ont he same problem....